# Добавление значения в DataGridViewComboBox из формы

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

На форме2 (c# winforms vs2010 net4.0) есть DataGridView1, в котором есть DatagridviewCombobox. Подскажите пожалуйста, как осуществить следующее для DatagridviewCombobox: при щелчке на стрелку dropdown открыть форму3 (на форме3 есть заполненный строками ListBox1 и кнопка "ок"), далее нужно при нажатии кнопки "ок" вернуть выделенную строку из ListBox1 в качестве значения для DatagridviewCombobox и форму3 закрыть?
Код ниже работает, но не получается корректно закрыть список DatagridviewCombobox, т.е после щелчка на стрелку dropdown (в DatagridviewCombobox) открывается форма3, затем на форме3 выбирается одна строка в ListBox1 и нажимается кнопка "ок"(btn1), в результате не получается назначить значение ячейке DatagridviewCombobox не отображая раскрывающейся список.

Код формы2:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        private DataSet InitializeDataSet()
        {
            //...код загрузки всех таблиц из файла mdb 
            return ds;
        }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataSet ds = InitializeDataSet();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        ComboBox cb6;
        DataGridViewCell currentCell;

        private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)    //cb6
            {
                if (e.Control is ComboBox)
                {
                    cb6 = (ComboBox)e.Control;
                    if (cb6 != null)
                    {
                        cb6.DropDown += new EventHandler(cb6_DropDown);
                    }
                    currentCell = DataGridView1.CurrentCell;
                }
            }
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cb6 != null)
            {
                cb6.DropDown -= new EventHandler(cb6_DropDown);
            }
        }

        //Добавить строку:
        private void btnAddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = DataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            index++;
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }

        //Показать форму3:
        private void cb6_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 frm3 = new Form3();

            //список для ListBox1:
            DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables["СПИСОК1"];
            ArrayList List1 = new ArrayList();
            foreach (DataRow item in dt1.Rows)
            {
                List1.Add(item["Полное_название"].ToString());
            }
            frm3.ListBox1.DataSource = null;
            frm3.ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            frm3.ListBox1.DataSource = List1;

            if (frm3.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell Col6 = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["Column6"];
                Col6.Items.Add(frm3.getItem1());
                Col6.Value = "";
                Col6.Value = frm3.getItem1();
              DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                DataGridView1.EndEdit();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            frm3.Close();
            frm3.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Код формы3:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btn1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            btn2.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        public string getItem1()
        {
            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                return ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            else
                return String.Empty;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Когда вы редактируете ячейку в `DataGridView`, то для нее создается объект `Editor`'а, который отображается на месте ячейки. Если вы пытаетесь изменить стандартное поведение `Editor`'а, то вам следует записывать новое значение именно в `Editor`, а не в `DataGridView` напрямую. Попробуйте в методе `cb6_DropDown` изменять текст в объекте `((ComboBox)sender)`, а не в объекте `DataGridView1`.

Comment: Странноватый дизайн. Если ComboBox никогда не используется по прямому назначению, то может стоит его заменить на что-нибудь другое? Например, обычный TextBox и рядом с ним Button? Ну то есть две колонки.

Comment: В метод cb6_DropDown добавила: ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender; comboBox.Items.Add(frm3.getItem1()); comboBox.Text = frm3.getItem1();. В результате frm3.getItem1() в списке появляется, но после comboBox.Text = frm3.getItem1(); выходит сообщение "Недопустимое значение DataGridViewComboBoxCell. Выполните обработку DataError". Т.е. не могу присвоить значение комбобоксу DataGridViewComboBoxCell. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно обойти эту ошибку?

Comment: @olga. Editor возвращает обратно в DataGridView только новое значение ячейки. Если вы добавляете новое значение в список выбора, то вам его нужно добавить и в Editor, и в сам столбец.